# Camera view and Render out being clipped even at 1,000,000 End clipping

Tags: clipping

I'm on Blender 3.0 and something weird going on with the camera, i set the End Clip at 100,000m (i even tried 1,000,000) but the render out is being clipped. Is there another setting i need to set? The file is at https://pasteall.org/blend/5bbdd1b2a77747a983066f83811991be

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View clipping is just for the viewport.  Each camera has its own settings.

Select the camera and then hit the green camera button on the bottom right to find the camera clipping settings.

Comment: ooooh yeah, i do remember i had to set it somewhere else. that was on the camera then. hmmm but a bit confusing for new users. any idea why CTRL+ALT+0 doesn't align the cam to my viewport view? it aligns randomly somewhere else, like far below the ground.

Comment: I could only guess numlock, maybe.  It's not a function I use much.